# Passing worksheets to a procedure

Tags: vba, excel, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass three worksheets to a procedure call as

```
Call pivot_table(Sheets("Sheet2"), Sheets("Sheet3"), Sheets("Sheet4"))
```

But i get an error `SUBSCRIPT OUT OF RANGE`

also if I try as

```
Dim ws, ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet3")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet4")
Call pivot_table(ws, ws1, ws2)
```

I get  the error as `ByRef arguement type mismatch`

My procedure is

```
Sub pivot_table(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet)
```

Not able to find the appropriate solution.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have sheets named "Sheet2", "Sheet3", and "Sheet4" in the workbook? If not, this is the reason for your Subscript out of range error.

The reason for the ByRef argument type mismatch is that your declaration of ws, ws1 and ws2 is not declaring all three as Worksheets.

VBA does not support this kind of multi-variable assignment on one line. If you want to declare on one line, you still have to explicitly declare the type of each variable, i.e.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
```

Declaring without a type will create a Variant variable, i.e. ws , ws1 : Variant, ws2 : Worksheet.